# Software design for adding aspects dynamically without AOP Framework

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator, interceptor, aop

I have written a little example program to measure the time execution of java methods.
I want to design a solution which is **low coupled** and which **can be added to other methods dynamically**, which means that if I wrote other classes with other methods, I want to *wrap my performance measuring module over my business logic module* and measure the time execution of the methods while the business logic class has **no dependencies to the performance measurement module**.

**My current solutions looks like this**

- I have an abstract class which defines some list operations.
- I have sub-classes which defines the concrete list operations
- I have a performance Measurement Class which extends the class which shall be measured

  ```
  public abstract class ListOperations<T> {

    private List<T> list;

    public ListOperations() {
       initList();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the list. Clients can decide which list type shall be used (e.g LinkedList, ArrayList etc.)
     */
    public abstract void initList();

    public abstract void addLast(final T element);

    public List<? super T> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    protected void setList(final List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
  }




  public class LinkedListOperations<T> extends ListOperations<T> {

  public LinkedListOperations() {
      super();
  }

  @Override
  public void addLast(final T element) {
      getList().addLast(element);
  }

  @Override
  public void initList() {
      setList(new LinkedList<T>());
  }

  @Override
  public LinkedList<? super T> getList() {
      return (LinkedList<? super T>) super.getList();
  }
  }



  public class PerformanceMeassuredLinkedListOperations<T> extends LinkedListOperations<T> {

  private static final String START_PERFORMANCE_MEASSURE_FOR_METHOD = "Start Performance Meassure for method: ";
  private static final String STOP_PERFORMANCE_MEASSURE_FOR_METHOD = "Stop Performance Meassure for method: ";
  private static final String TIME_EXECUTION_IN_MILLIS = "Time Execution in Millis: ";

  /**
   * Used to printout the name of the method from the stack. in depth 2 the real business logic method is located
   */
  private static final int DEPTH_IN_STACKTRACE = 2;
  // depth 0 = printStopMeassurement
  // depth 1 = stopPerformanceMeassure
  // depth 2 = method for which performance is measured (e.g addLast)

  private long startCurrentTimeMillis;

  @Override
  public void initList() {
      startPerformanceMeassure();
      super.initList();
      stopPerformanceMeassure();
  }

  public void meassureAddLast(final int numberOfElements, final T testElement) {
      startPerformanceMeassure();
      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
          addLast(testElement);
      }
      stopPerformanceMeassure();
  }

  protected void startPerformanceMeassure() {
      printStartMeassurement();
      startCurrentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  private void printStartMeassurement() {
      System.out.println(START_PERFORMANCE_MEASSURE_FOR_METHOD + getNameOfCurrentExecutedMethod());
  }

  protected void stopPerformanceMeassure() {
      System.out.println(TIME_EXECUTION_IN_MILLIS + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startCurrentTimeMillis));
      printStopMeassurement();
  }

  private void printStopMeassurement() {
      System.out.println(STOP_PERFORMANCE_MEASSURE_FOR_METHOD + getNameOfCurrentExecutedMethod());
  }

  private String getNameOfCurrentExecutedMethod() {
      final StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
      return ste[ste.length - DEPTH_IN_STACKTRACE].getMethodName();
  }

  }



  public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      PerformanceMeassuredLinkedListOperations<String> listOperations = new PerformanceMeassuredLinkedListOperations<String>();
      listOperations.meassureAddLast(50000, "Hello");
  }
  }
  ```

With this solution I must extend every business logic module and add my time measurement code in a static way.

Now I want to design a **performance measure module that can be added dynamically to any business logic module** and measures the performance of the methods called. I don't want to use any AOP Framwork for that. I think such a dynamical aspect addition can be done with a mixture of some kind of decorator and interceptor pattern but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is a *[cross cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern)*
Your needs fall squarely into the realm of an aspect. You want to be able to log latency across various cut-points in your code.

Consider:

**Method 1**

- You will need to intercept all calls to said business modules.
- You can define an `BussinessModule` interface. Create a delegate class that intercepts this common call and then wraps an abstract method and logs latency (or whatever).
- It's limited but, with some effort can work and it's the easiest implementation.

**Method 2**

- Develop some sort of expressive language to say which methods you want to intercept on what classes
- Figure out a way to intercept those method calls (Without using AspectJ, or writing your own class-loader, I can't imagine how) and execute them

Method 1 is not at all *dynamic*. You must have iron control of implementation across your whole system. Any class that doesn't get included in your delegate/proxy scheme won't get this behavior. Someone has to make sure that every class implemented has this *wrapper* on it.

Method 2 is super dynamic. By having an expressive language/syntax you can describe code to get wrapper and then, even if it's not your code or you're working with lazy people, it still gets wrapped. The downside is that it would be insanely difficult and time consuming to implement. **Good new though! Spring AOP and AspectJ already do this!**

So, your question was

> how do I do this without Spring AOP or AspectJ

I believe I have given an answer. But to be totally clear: Lots-and-lots of delegation would be the easiest route.

That said: There is no good explainable reason to roll your own. I literally have an Aspect and the bean config for Spring to do exactly this. If it's a question of time I can simply paste it in and you can rip it off and run with it.

Comment: There are actually very few things that aspects are unquestionably good for and this is one of them.

Comment: That's the other one. :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to use a proven and tested framework because you alone can do better and exchange one framework for another - your own one. Be it as it may, you will be ending up using a framework. Does that make sense?

Good luck for re-inventing the wheel.

**Update:** Some more background about why I think you will be ending up implementing your own AOP framework: AOP is kind of orthogonal to OOP's inheritance concept. An OOP language without any semantic extensions like AspectJ or frameworks like Spring AOP just does not offer the means to express aspects, otherwise AOP languages/frameworks would be redundant. I doubt you will be able to solve the problem by a mere combination of two or so OOP design patterns.

**Update 2:** If you fail with design patterns and byte code generation is too complex for you, you might want to use the same approach as Spring AOP: Java dynamic proxies (works for interfaces) and/or CGLIB dynamic proxies (for non-interface types).

Comment: I'm not searching for a solution for a real-world problem (I would probably use Spring and its AOP module for that). I'm just searching for possible designs to handle such situations with POJOs and without any frameworks. This is just for practice design patterns and software design.

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea it was just an academical excercise. I use AOP (AspectJ, not the poor-featured Spring AOP) a lot in real life, so I know what I am talking about. Especially if you want to measure performance, a proxy approach would introduce a lot of indirection overhead, thus my remark. AspectJ is superior because it does not use any proxies, it directly adds bytecode to methods. You are trying to rebuild Spring AOP, in a way. Good luck anyway, and I mean it. Please post your results, if any.

Comment: @kriegaex The main problem with the proxy approach is not so much performance but local calls. If you've got a proxied class which contains a method call: `public void foo() { this.bar(); }`, `bar()` will never be called through the proxy. This may sometimes be what you want but more often than not it isn't.

Comment: Yeah sure, I know. That's why I always use AspectJ, Spring AOP is just "AOP light" IMHO. ;-)